# Show that $ℤ^{m}$ is a subgroup (and a free abelian group) of $ℤ^{n}$ for all $m≤n$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

My **question** is: Show that $ℤ^{m}$ is a subgroup (and a free abelian group) of $ℤ^{n}$ for all $0≤m≤n$.

Comment: What have you tried? This follows pretty straightforwardly from the definitions.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer: Can you give a me an idea to start.

Comment: @DER First, prove that $\mathbb Z^m$ is a subgroup. Do it by definition, that is, prove that it is closed under inversion and addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m \le n$, then you can embed $\mathbb{Z}^m$ inside $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in the obvious way by the map
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_m,0,\ldots,0)$$
This is obviously an embedding (ie, an injective homomorphism)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What are possible (and simple) generators of $\mathbb{Z}^m$?