# What are the other methods used to prove that a homomorphism is bijective?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, applications

The motivation can be found in: [Show that $ℤ^{m}$ is a subgroup (and a free abelian group) of $ℤ^{n}$ for all $m≤n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806411/show-that-%E2%84%A4m-is-a-subgroup-and-a-free-abelian-group-of-%E2%84%A4n-for-all-m).

In a **specified problem** related to a **dynamical system** the only possibility is $m=n$. Here $m$ and $n$ have special meanings: $m$ is the cardinal of a population $A$ and $n$ is the cardinal of a population $B$.

I want to construct a bijction between $\mathbb{Z}^m$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$ (I mean that I try to prove that $m=n$). I have proved that $m≤n$. So there is an injective homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}^m$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$. I want now to prove that this map is also surjective. However, I have no idea to start.

My **question** is: What are the other methods used to prove that a homomorphism is bijective? I have tried to use a **non-degenerate quadratic form**. But I have no idea to start.

Also, I'll need the identity elements of $\mathbb{Z}^m$ to be mapped to the identity of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. But, there is some related problems in this way.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking for a bijection between $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$? If so, there's always the identity map.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, but not in this direct way. I have $m≤n$, but I know also that the only case is $m=n$.

Comment: Show that it's surjective, and show that the kernel of the homomorphism is trivial ($\ker \phi = \{0\}$).

Comment: @M.Vinay: This is not possible since we have $m≤n$.

Comment: It sounds as if you are using the notation $\mathbb{Z}^m$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in some nonstandard way. The question that you link to has answers which clearly lay out the standard meanings of $\mathbb{Z}^m$ and $\mathbb{Z}^n$, and clearly show that the identity map is a bijective homomorphism. So if you have something different in mind, you will need to explain it better if you wish to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: To prove a map is injective, assume two elements of the domain are mapped to the same element of the codomain and obtain a contradiction. To prove a map is surjective, given an arbitrary element of the codomain, prove there exists an element in the domain that is sent to it. Alternatively, to prove a map is bijective, one can explicitly specify an inverse map and prove that it is such.

Comment: Right, it's not possible for $m \le n$. I thought you were asking only about $m = n$. If $m < n$, you *cannot* have a (group) isomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^m$ to $\mathbb{Z}^n$. So what are you asking?

Comment: You say "in a specified problem [...]." Since you've managed to confuse your readers with things that don't make sense, do you think it would be possible to provide a verbatim quote of the original problem and let us understand it for you?

Comment: In order to prove (1) you need the hypothesis of (2); so why are these separate? Is (1) something you're supposed to prove, or a true/false question, or what? It doesn't have a question mark or any instructions. If you "also" know that $m=n$, then why in the world are you saying $m\le n$ over and over again when you should just say $m=n$? Why in the world is the identity map $\Bbb Z^m\to\Bbb Z^n$ when $m=n$ not enough for you? What are you *actually* interested in? (Also, groups do not have "identity elements" *plural*; the identity element of any group is unique.)

Comment: @LeeMosher: No, the sets have the standard meaning.

Comment: So you are given that there is an injective homomorphism $\Bbb Z^m\to\Bbb Z^n$ and from that you need to prove $m\le n$? That's not stated anywhere in your question. I have downvoted this post; please rewrite it in plain, clear language and stop yanking us around so I can revoke it.

Comment: @seaturtles: Ok, I have edited the question.

Comment: This is beginning to make a little more sense, but not quite enough sense. When you write "the only possibility is $m=n$", do you mean that you are trying to **prove** that $m=n$, or do you mean that you already **know** that $m=n$?

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, I mean that I try to prove that $m=n$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: I have posted a partial solution to the problem based on your conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a thought. Suppose that you have an injective homomorphism
$f : \mathbb{Z}^m \to \mathbb{Z}^n
$ and you want to prove that $m=n$. While it would be sufficient to prove that the homomorphism is surjective, that is not necessary. Here are two necessary and sufficient conditions for $m=n$, which are useful in different situations:

- $image(f)$ has finite index in $\mathbb{Z}^n$
- $image(f)$ is "cobounded" in $\mathbb{Z}^n$, meaning that there exists a constant $D \ge 0$ such that for each $p \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}^m$ such that $d(p,f(q)) \le D$.

Comment: @ Lee Mosher: The two conditions are separate and each one of them implies that $m=n$. Here $d$ is any distance defined in $ℤ^{n}$. I am right!.

Comment: Yes, they are separate: $m=n \iff$ (first $\bullet$) $\iff$ (second $\bullet$). And yes, $d$ is any distance.

Comment: Well… not quite "any" distance. For $d$ you can use the ordinary distance using the Pythagorean formula. Or you can use any distance which is defined by a norm on the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$ such as the taxicab metric. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaxicabMetric.html. This is probably enough to cover whatever distances you might be inclined to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the Lee Mosher conditions to poste this solution. However, there a litle problem with it.

If $m≤n$, then we can embed $ℤ^{m}$ inside $ℤ^{n}$ in the obvious way by the map $$θ₁:ℤ^{m}→ℤⁿ:θ₁(z₁,…,z_{m})=(z₁,…,z_{m},0,…,0)$$

I will use the second equivalent form in the Lee Mosher answer.

There exists a constant $D≥0$ such that for each $p=(p₁,....,p_{n})∈ℤⁿ$ there exists $q=(q₁,....,q_{m})∈ℤ^{m}$ such that $$d((p₁,....,p_{n}),(q₁,....,q_{m},0,...,0))≤D$$

We have $$d((p₁,....,p_{n}),(q₁,....,q_{m},0,...,0))=√(∑_{i=1}^{n}(p_{i}-q_{i})²)=√(∑_{i=1}^{m}(p_{i}-q_{i})²+∑_{i=m+1}^{n}p_{i}²)$$

We can choose $$(q₁,…,q_{m})=(p₁,…,p_{m})$$

So we get 
    $$d((p₁,....,p_{n}),(q₁,....,q_{m},0,...,0))=√(∑_{i=m+1}^{n}p_{i}²)$$

This quantity does not exist since we want to prove that $m=n$.